# Homogenous measure on the positive real halfline

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, geometric-measure-theory

> Define a measure $\mu\not=0$ on positive real number $\Bbb R_{>0}$ such that for any measurable set $E\subset\Bbb R_{>0}$ and $a\in \Bbb R_{>0} $, we have $\mu(aE)= \mu(E)$, where $aE=[ax;x\in E]$.

---

I am totally blank about this problem. I ponder on it several times but didn't get any idea. This exercise illustrates lebesgue measure's abstract and weird nature. Because if we assume E as a subset of real numbers or any interval, it totally disagrees to fulfill this translation.

Comment: Start with an interval $(b,c)$.  We want $\mu((b,c)) = \mu((ab,ac))$.  Can you find a function $f(x)$ so that $f(ac) - f(ab) = f(c) - f(b)$?

Comment: Another hint: Consider the bijection $\exp\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. How does the Lebesgue measure look if we 'push it forward' along $\exp$?

Comment: this is haar measure on $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot)$, easy to find with the exponential map from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot)$ and using haar measure on $(\mathbb{R},+)$

Comment: Oh I see, I never heard about haar measure before let me do some study about it. Thank you guys.

Comment: A combination of Abel's and yoyo's comments that might be easier to understand: Lebesgue measure is invariant under *adding* a constant; $\mu(a+E)=\mu(E)$. You want a measure invariant under *multiplication* by a constant.  Fortunately, the exponential function converts addition to multiplication. (In ancient times, you would have seen the desired measure on your slide rule.  Nowadays, I suppose slide rules can be seen in some museums.)

Comment: Wow, I mean really nice insight and decent conclusion @AndreasBlass . Thank you for adding and elaborating the idea. 
And you're right, slide rules only deserve that place nowadays. :) In mathematics, there is no more room for obvious things; actually abstractness is the beauty of this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer in greater generality.

A common way to construct a measure is to take a  nonnegative  locally integrable function $w$ and define $\mu(E)=\int_E w(x)\,dx$. This does not give all measures (only those that are absolutely continuous with respect to $dx$) but for many examples that's enough.

In terms of $w$, the desired condition translates to 
$$\int_E w(x)\,dx = \int_{aE} w(x)\,dx\tag1$$ 
A way to get a handle on (1) is to bring both integrals to the same domain of integration. So, change the variable $x=ay$ in the second one, so that it becomes $\int_{E} a\,w(ay)\,dy$. Which is the same as $\int_{E} a\,w(ax)\,dx$, because the name of the integration variable does not matter. So, (1)  takes the form
$$\int_E w(x)\,dx = \int_{E} a\, w(ax)\,dx \tag2$$
or, better yet, 
$$\int_E ( w(x)-a\, w(ax))\,dx \tag3$$
So that (3) holds for every measurable set, the integrand should be zero almost everywhere. So, we need a function $w$ such that $w(ax)=w(x)/a$ for all $x$. In particular, $w(a)=w(1)/a$ for all $a$, which tells us what the function is. (The value of $w(1)$ can be chosen to be any positive number).

---

The above can be generalized to produce measures such that $$\mu(aE) =a^p \mu(E)$$ for all $a>0$, where $p$ can be any fixed real number.

Comment: Oh thank you so much my friend for answering in such an elaborative and general way.

Comment: But I've a question (may be the silly one): Why did you restrict this function to be locally integrable? Please give me the reason for such construction. 
Again thanks a ton.

Comment: @SaraTancredi If I want to write $\int_E w(x)\,dx$, I must be able to explain why the integral makes sense. It certainly does if $w$ is integrable on $(0,\infty)$ and $E$ is a measurable set. Unfortunately this is too restrictive, because the functions we want to use here (like $1/x$) are not integrable on $(0,\infty)$.  Another option is to nonnegative measureable functions $w$, because for them $\int_E w(x)\,dx$ is defined, although it could possibly be $+\infty$.  This is what I could have done.

Comment: @SaraTancredi But I somehow felt that finite intervals such as $[1,2]$ should have finite measure, although this was not explicitly stated in the problem. So I said that $w$ should be  locally integrable. After all, the goal is to give an example, not to prove a general statement about $w$. So I could have asked $w$ to also be continuous, strictly positive, differentiable and so on... I would just be making things harder for myself, by restricting the set of possible examples.

Comment: I got your point @75064. I was just wondering about the restrictions and now I realized that you made everything clear to avoid any doubt on your proof. :)
Again thanks for your help and precious time.